# Count Lines Viewed from command 'less'

Tags: command-line

I run command `less`

```
ls /usr/bin | less
```

got many lines of directories.

```
2to3-
2to3-2.7
AssetCacheLocatorUtil
AssetCacheManagerUtil
AssetCacheTetheratorUtil
BuildStrings
CpMac
...
```

How to enumerate them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to its man page:

```
-N or --LINE-NUMBERS
      Causes  a  line  number to be displayed at the beginning of each
      line in the display.
```

So:

```
ls /usr/bin | less -N
  1 2to3
  2 2to3-
  3 2to3-2.7
  4 2to32.6
  ....
```